# cudaMemcpyAsync from page-locked host memory to device memory returns reading access violation error

Tags: concurrency, cuda

I am coding a memory-heavy multi-GPU CUDA program. I found that my `cudaMemcpyAsync` calls werent actually performed asynchronously. After some research I found out that I would have to copy it from page-locked `host` memory to the device. So what I now attempt to do is to copy a part of the whole `host` input data array into a chunk of page-locked `host` memory, and then copy that to the `device`. The H2H `cudaMemcpyAsync` works fine without outputting any errors, the H2D afterwards gives me this error: `Access violation reading address 0xWHATEVER`. Additionally, in the sample code I am providing there is an identical error with the `cudaMallocHost` call. (this works fine in the main project)

I have tried to make a much simpler sample project (the one below). This still gives me errors, so I don't really know what to do.

```
#include "cuda.h"
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>

#ifndef KERNEL_H
#define KERNEL_H
typedef struct
{
    int device = 0;
    double  *d_array,   //device array ptr
        *h_array_pl; //page locked array ptr
} IOdataPtr;
#endif

void printCudaError(cudaError_t error, char err_src[]) { //error printing function to reduce line count
    if (error != cudaSuccess) {
        printf("Error: %i while performing %s \n", error, err_src);
    }
}



int main() {

    const int GPU_N = 2;
    const int CALC_N = 1024*1024*1024;

    cudaError_t error;
    cudaStream_t stream[GPU_N];

    double *h_array;
    h_array = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double) * CALC_N);

    for (int i = 0; i < CALC_N; i++) {
        h_array[i] = 2;
    }

    IOdataPtr ptr[GPU_N];

    for (int i = 0; i < GPU_N; i++) {
        //normal host alloc

        ptr[i].device = i;
        error = cudaSetDevice(ptr[i].device); //select device
        printCudaError(error, "cudaSetDevice");

        cudaStreamCreate(&stream[i]);
        printCudaError(error, "cudaStreamCreate");

        error = cudaMalloc((void**)&(ptr[i].d_array), 
                            CALC_N / GPU_N * sizeof(double));
        printCudaError(error, "cudaMalloc");

        error = cudaMallocHost((void **)&ptr[i].h_array_pl, 
                                CALC_N / GPU_N * sizeof(double));
        printCudaError(error, "cudaMallocHost");

        //xre
        //data -> pl
        error = cudaMemcpyAsync(ptr[i].h_array_pl,                  //dst
                                &h_array[i * CALC_N / GPU_N],       //src
                                CALC_N / GPU_N * sizeof(double),    //amt
                                cudaMemcpyHostToHost,               //kind
                                stream[i]);                         //stream
        printCudaError(error, "cudaMemcpyAsync H2H");

        //pl -> dev
        error = cudaMemcpyAsync(ptr[i].d_array,                     //dst
                                ptr[i].h_array_pl,                  //src
                                CALC_N / GPU_N * sizeof(double),    //amt
                                cudaMemcpyHostToDevice,             //kind
                                stream[i]);                         //stream
        printCudaError(error, "cudaMemcpyAsync H2D");

        cudaStreamDestroy(stream[i]);
        error = cudaFree(ptr[i].d_array);
        printCudaError(error, "cudaFree");
    }
    printf("Well it worked");
    free(h_array);
    getchar();

}
```

The output my code gives me:

```
Error: 2 while performing cudaMallocHost
Error: 2 while performing cudaMemcpyAsync H2H
Error: 2 while performing cudaMemcpyAsync H2D
Error: 2 while performing cudaFree
Well it worked
```

`Error 2` is `cudaErrorMemoryAllocation`

Comment: The code in your question is horribly broken. You never create any streams or initialize either `ptr` or `stream`. How do you imagine anything predicable could possibly happen?

Comment: @talonmies my excuses. I had forgotten to create the stream in this sample program. Thank you for pointing it out. I have changed it in both this question and in my code. The error I get also got updated, which still is an issue with the ```cudaMallocHost```

Comment: Still broken. Stream creation before device selection won't work as you intend and you still are not assigning any values to ptr[i].device before calling cudaSetDevice, so you are running all this on one GPU

Comment: @talonmies my apologies again. I updated it again, I hope theres nothing wrong with it anymore now in that regard. If so, my excuses. I also added the error I get in my main project.

Comment: Once again (is this the third time in three questions?), when I compile and run your updated code, I get no errors. It just runs to completion

Comment: @talonmies to be completely sure that I have the same code as I posted here I copied it from here into my sample project again  and compiled it. It doesnt work, the error with ```cudaMallocHost``` persists

Comment: I can't help you with a problem I can't reproduce, sorry

Comment: @talonmies Could you maybe give me some information about the environment you ran the code in? What CUDA version did you use? (9.2 for me) What IDE did you use? (VS2015) What GPU setup do you have? (2x RTX2080Ti)

Comment: I tried it on another machine with CUDA 9.2, the source code doesnt work there either

Comment: Linux with CUDA 9., maxwell GPU. What happens if you just run the code in your question  on one GPU rather than two?

Comment: I tried it with ```GPU_N = 1``` instead of ```2```. It still gives me the same error. It came to my mind though that it might be because I am using a CUDA version that is older than my GPUs, is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code you currently have posted, this line of code is wrong:

```
error = cudaMemcpyAsync(ptr[i].d_array, &ptr[i].h_array_pl, CALC_N / GPU_N * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice, stream[i]);
                                        ^
```

That ampersand doesn't belong there. `ptr[i].h_array_pl` is already a pointer to the source of the data transfer, you should not be taking the address of that pointer.

Using the address of this pointer as the data source of the copy operation would result in incorrect and illegal host memory accesses, for the size of the transfer indicated in this code.  Whether or not this would be detected depends on a number of factors, but it's possibly or probably the reason for the `Access violation reading location...` report, which is generally referring to an illegal access to host memory.

Comment: I just found that too today! There is another error persisting though: With the updated code (i updated it right now) it gives me ```Error 2 (cudaErrorMemoryAllocation)``` for  ```cudaMallocHost, cudaMemcpyAsync H2H, cudaMemcpyAsync H2D and cudaFree```. It only does that for large enough input sizes, e.g ```const int CALC_N = 1024*1024*1024;```. The error doesnt appear for sizes smaller than that (e.g. ```1024*1024*512```). In my main project it still does not give proper output even if the error doesnt appear. What am I doing wrong while allocation the page-locked host memory?

Comment: This is of course a completely different problem.  When you have a new question on SO, you are supposed to ask a new question, not start a completely new line of questioning in the comments.  My guess would be your windows system doesn't want to give you 8 GB of pinned memory.  Changing your question to a completely different one is confusing and now makes my answer confusing to future readers.